# How to have drawings inside Android view scale to dimensions of view?

Tags: android, scale, ondraw

Im trying to make a custom view with some drawings in it. I want these drawings to take up the entire view but I also want the view to maintain a certain height/width ratio for these drawings.

Comment: see `Matrix#setRectToRect` and `Canvas#concat`

Answer (score 0):

In your `onDraw(canvas)` method, use `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()` get to get the entire `width` and `height` of the `View`. Use this detail (like calculating the center of the View (`width/2`,`height/2`)) to draw your drawings. This way they will always fill the entire view and maintain the right aspect ratio.